# override default search paths of cshtml files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I try to minify my javascript in the cshtml razor files and save it as viewname.min.cshtml.
Is it possible to override the search when I call return View() or PartialView() in a controller to search first for a name.min.cshtml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a `RazorViewEngine` with your own values for the `ViewLocationFormats` property.